# Parametrized curve tangent to a line

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm working from Do Carmo's book Differential Geometry, and I was a bit confused about one question - 1.3.5 in particular.

The question asks:

> Let $\alpha:(-1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a parametrized curve given by
>
> $\alpha(t) = (\frac{3at}{1+t^3},\frac{3at^2}{1+t^3})$ (presumably $a \in \mathbb{R}$)
>
> a) Prove that, at $t=0$, $\alpha$ is tangent to the $x$-axis

At first, I thought this means that we had to show that $\alpha(0)$ was on the $x$-axis and $\alpha'(0) \neq 0$, but I realized that $\alpha(t)$ is the tangent curve here, not $\alpha'(t)$.
Now, I'm not sure what exactly I should do. $\alpha(0) = (0,0)$ so doesn't that disqualify it from being a tangent line at $t=0$ according to Do Carmo? I assume I'm supposed to integrate $\alpha(t)$ and check that the value attained at $t=0$ lies on the $x$-axis?

Comment: No, you need to compute $\alpha'(0)$.

Comment: Really you only need to show that $\alpha_{2}'(t) = (\frac{3at^2}{1+t^3})' = 0$. Why? (one should also show that $\alpha_{1}'(t) \neq 0$, if you want to be precise).

Comment: @TedShifrin what confuses me here is that, according to the book, $\beta'(t)$ is said to be the tangent curve to $\beta(t)$ But here, $\alpha(t)$ itself is said to be the tangent curve.

I found that $\alpha'(0) = (3a,0)$

Comment: @ChrisK Because then the point would be on the $x$-axis, correct?  However, it seems to me that we're talking about $\alpha$ being tangent to some curve instead of tangent curves to $\alpha$.

Comment: You are confusing "alpha is tangent" and "alpha is *the* tangent". As others have told you, all you have to do is show that $\alpha(0) = (0,0)$ and that $\alpha'(0)$ is in the direction of the $x$-axis.

Comment: @bubba Alright, I understand what I need to do.  However, how exactly is $\alpha$ is tangent to different than $\alpha$ is the tangent to? The question is phrased in a way that suggests $\alpha$ is the tangent.
I want to clarify so I can avoid this misunderstanding in the future.

Comment: English is a tricky language. If I say "$\alpha$ is tangent to the $x$-axis at the point $P$" I mean that the the tangent line of $\alpha$ at the point $P$ is the $x$-axis. It's a statement about the shape of the curve $\alpha$ at the point $P$. If I say "$\beta$ is the tangent curve of $\alpha$", then (according to the definition you gave) I mean that $\beta(t) = \alpha'(t)$ for all $t$. This is a statement about the relationship between entire curves $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Different, right?

Comment: @bubba I see what's going on here - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

s[image]

The curve looks to be the Folium of Descartes. Although it is   parametrized so that
a self-intersection is avoided, I've shown the whole curve. It does appear to  be tangent to the x-axis. It's also tangent to the y-axis at the origin but that part of the curve would not be present with the parametrization you presented.

Comment: That is the picture the book provided, but I'm looking to prove it rigorously.

Comment: alpha(t) =  (x(t),y(t)) , alpha'(t) = (x(t)' , y(t)') .