# Finding limit of a parametrized curve

Tags: differential-geometry

Related to this question: [Parametrized curve tangent to a line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652819/parametrized-curve-tangent-to-a-line?noredirect=1#comment1374973_652819)

I'm working on Do Carmo 1.3.5c, which is:

> Given a parametrized curve $\alpha(t) = (\frac{3at}{1+t^3},\frac{3at^2}{1+t^3})$ and the tangent curve $\alpha'(t) = (\frac{3a}{1+t^3}-\frac{9at^3}{(1+t^3)^2},\frac{6at}{1+t^3}-\frac{9at^4}{(1+t^3)^2})$, show that the limit of both $\alpha(t)$ and $\alpha'(t)$ as $t \to -1$ approaches the line $x+y+a=0$

My guess is that the line can be written as $(u,-a-u)$ and I'd have to show that $|u-\alpha(t)| \to 0$ and similarly for $\alpha'(t)$, but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach.  Could anyone direct me into the right approach?

Comment: The limit should be $\lim_{t \to -1} \frac{y^.}{x^.}$

Comment: @Semsem Not sure if I quite understand what you mean.

Comment: The slope of the tangent is $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^.}{x^.}$ and the point is given by substitution in $\alpha$ by $t=-1$

Comment: @Samson Still not sure what you're referring to, sorry.  Edited the question to clear something up - I want to know the limit of both $\alpha(t)$ and $\alpha'(t)$ as $t \to -1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the following proposition which you can either take as a definition, admit -maybe some version of it is in Do Carmo, I don't know-, or prove:

> **Proposition** Let $t \mapsto \alpha(t) = (x(t), y(t))$ be a parametrized curve in the plane.  Assume that $\lim_{t\to t_0} \Vert \alpha(t) \Vert = +\infty$. The straight line $ax + by + c = 0$ is an asymptote of the curve $\alpha$ iff $\lim_{t\to t_0} ax(t) + by(t) + c = 0.$

Comment: That would work, but the issue is that it seems a bit of a reach from the point where I am now.  So far, Do Carmo hasn't said anything other than defining a (regular) parametrized curve and arc length.

Comment: Well, it's not hard to show this proposition. Assume that $b \neq 0$ (the case $b=0$ can be treated separately, anyway you don't care about that case in your problem). Let $M(t)$ be the point on the line $ax + by + c = 0$ with abscissa $x(t)$. What is the ordinate $\tilde{y}(t)$ of $M(t)$? Conclude that $\Vert \alpha(t) - M(t) \Vert \to 0$ when $t \to t_0$.

Comment: Where Can I find this proposition? I´m trying find a book about this